# Error when typing C-0 C-k in minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer

It is from yesterday that emacs behaves in an unexpected way, as I will now explain.
If I open emacs and I open the minibuffer with C-x C-f and the I press M-0 C-k, emacs deletes the line, this is the normal behaviour.
If now I exit from the minibuffer, pressing for instance C-g and the I reenter with C-x C-f and I press again M-0 C-k, this error appears! [image]

Has anybody any idea of what it may be?

For the moment I delete the line using C-a C-k, but I would like to understand why the second time that I try M-0 C-k it gives me an error and not the first, also this behaviour appeared recently (I am installing a lot of packages, it may be that, I do not know). 
What about your emacs? How does it behave?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Emacs 25.1.50.1. Have you tried starting with `emacs -Q`? If you can't reproduce the problem with `emacs -Q`, there's something in your config (.emacs.d/init.el  or ~/.emacs) that has caused it.

Comment: You might want to bind a key to `delete-minibuffer-contents` in `minibuffer-local-map`, and use that key instead.

Comment: @Tyler I cannot reproduce it with emacs -Q. I will look for the buggy part in my .emacs. When I will have found it I will post here what causes the problem.